# Get values from searched range to combo list

Tags: vba, excel

I have combo box, where I select for example name John. I need to insert all items, that can john sell into another combo box. These items are stored in a worksheet, where in first column is name of salesman and in second is item, which can be sold by salesman:

```
 A         B
John      Tires
John      Auto parts
John      Body kits
John      Rims 
Alex      Tires
Alex      Spoilers
```

I select `John` in *combo1* and I want to put all items from column B (tires, auto parts, body kits and rims) into *combo2*, where name `John` is written in column A. 
I already have code, which add sale mans into first combo:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cLoc As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("seller")
For Each cLoc In ws.Range("SellerTable")
   With Addinvoice.SellerCombo
    .AddItem cLoc.Value
   End With
Next cLoc
End Sub
```

If it is possible, the table, where rights to sale are stored, should be dynamic, so any person or competence to sell can be added by new line table. Same with seller names -now I have SellerTable range, but this solution isn't good, when I need to add or remove saleman.

Comment: On way is to loop to find what's selected in combobox1 and add each item found to combobox2. And the other way is to assign a *Named* Range and use *Rowsource* property. Oh btw, where are your comboboxes and what type?

Comment: Comboboxes are on *Form*..

Comment: Asking "How to do it?" on SO isn't polite. Showing us what you have tried and where it breaks is. If you can display some code showing how you are populating the comboboxes, you are more likely to get an answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's using the Named range. Set up your worksheet like below:

[image]

Then use below code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Select Case Me.ComboBox1
    Case "John": Me.ComboBox2.RowSource = "John"
    Case "Ales": Me.ComboBox2.RowSource = "Alex"
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "John"
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem "Alex"
End Sub
```

This is just an idea. You'll have to clean it up a bit and handle potential errors. HTH.

**Result:**

[image]